# How to bind WCF RIA Services query entity to the WPF label?

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf-ria-services

I really want to know why in the first case I can bind data to the DataGrid and in the second case it doesn't work at all. Thank you for any clue!!!

Here is the code:

```
        Guid id = Guid.Parse("BCBBF129-30ED-400B-9D63-403ED79FDFC7");
        EntityQuery<Alert> alert = this._preDomainContext.GetAlertQuery(id);  
        LoadOperation<Alert> l = this._preDomainContext.Load(alert);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = l.Entities; // <- It works fine

        label1.Content = l.Entities.ElementAt(0).Message; // It gives an error
```

And the XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGrid   AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="100" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,154,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
<sdk:Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="194,114,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

And error is:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

Oh! On both cases  when I debug I cannot see any values for the  **l.Entities** and as well as 
**l.Entities.ElementAt(0).Message**. But when page appears under the DataGrid I can see the data but at the same time I get the error above...

I am not sure... But is it possible to see the data before when a page appears? It's really uncomfortable don't see any data at all...

UPDATES:

```
    [RequiresAuthentication]
    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class PreDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<PreEntities>
    {


    public  Alert GetAlert(Guid id)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Alerts.Where(a=>a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: I just put the error!! Thanks for the reviewing!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your Entities collection is empty.

Comment: Yes. It is empty... But How it's possible that later data appears? Do u think it's because of some lazy binding issue or?

Comment: LoadOperation implements INotifyPropertyChanged, so your DataGrid binding knows to update itself when data appears. the whole point of LoadOperation is that it's asynchronous. If you want to know when the data is loaded, then subscribe to the Completed event.

Comment: Should I use something like this._preShowDomainContext.Load<Alert>(alert).Completed += (alert, args) =>
                {
                    
                    label1.Content = l.Entities.ElementAt(0).Message;
                };

Comment: I found the solution. 
The final code looks like this one:
     Guid id = Guid.Parse("BCBBF129-30ED-400B-9D63-403ED79FDFC7");
     EntityQuery<Alert> alert = this._preDomainContext.GetAlertQuery(id);  
     LoadOperation<Alert> l = this._preDomainContext.Load(alert);
     l.Completed += new EventHandler(l_Completed);    
      // and we need this method...
         void l_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { label1.Content = ((Alert(LoadOperation)sender).Entities.FirstOrDefault()).Message;
     }

Comment: And here is the another solution  this._preDomainContext.Load(alert).Completed += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    label1.Content = (((LoadOperation<Alert>)sender).Entities.FirstOrDefault()).Message;
                };